# MongoDB. Query data from 2 collections filtering in both

Tags: mongodb, collections, aggregate

I have 2 collections

```
products
{
 "_id":"1",
 "orderId":"1",
 "code":"beaf"
},
{
 "_id":"2",
 "orderId":"1",
 "code":"pork"
}
{
 "_id":"3",
 "orderId":"2",
 "code":"beaf"
}

orders
{
 "_id":"1",
 "paymentMethod": "creditCard"
},
{
 "_id":"2",
 "paymentMethod": "cash"
}
```

i need to get count of products with code "beaf" and paid by "creditCard" with best possible performance for about 1M records.

Is there any way to filter 2 collections separately and then match (lookup, unionWith) results to get better performance?

Below solution works correctly but takes ~15 seconds for one million products and 800K orders.

```
db.products.aggregate([
    { $match: { code: "beaf" } },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "orders",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "orderId",
            as: "order"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { order.paymentMethod: "creditCard" }
    },
    {
        $count: "count"
    }
]);
```

I think the reason of slow work is that orders are filtered after lookup stage.
Get count of filtered orders and products separately takes <1sec so it does not look like an index issue.

Attempts to use "facet" stage results in exceeding document size limit.